# How do I get a translator object in the ExceptionController using symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, exception, internationalization

Using symfony 3.4. When I need to translate something within a Controller, I do the following:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('termsAndConditions'),
```

How to do this within the ExceptionController, when I want to translate the error message showing, depending on the http status code? The Controller from namespace `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` has the trait `ControllerTrait` with the `get()` method. The ExceptionController under the namespace `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller` does not implement the `get()` method.

So how can I access the translator object?

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise to make any changes to `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller`, as it will be overriten when you update symfony itself.

If you wish to show custom error messages depending on HTTP status code then try [customizing the error pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html). I believe that you can simply use translator within those custom templates, like so:

```
<div>
    {{ 'termsAndConditions'|trans }}
</div>
```

Comment: Is using the twig bundle the only way? Can't I access the translator in the ExceptionController somehow?

Comment: Well, the `ExceptionController` is a part of TwigBundle itself, so it's not like you have to add anything or so. If you want, you can extend the `ExceptionController` and inject translator to that extended controller. You will find information on extending the controller in the link I gave in the answer.

Comment: If I create a template like you suggest in your answer, it will always load the english version. How do I tell him which language to choose for the *|trans?